# How to properly set up an lmer in R for a longitudinal design?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, longitudinal

I am trying to run an lmer model in R, and having trouble figuring out how to set it up properly - I've been reading about mixed models and watching tutorials but still can't figure it out. The data involves patients who have a surgical procedure. I want to see how much a structure in their brain (the thalamus) changes between baseline and 6 months. I have baseline and 6-month measures of the thalamus for each subject. For each subject, I also have their age, total intracranial volume, and the energy used to perform the treatment. I am particularly interested to know:
A) Does the thalamus volume change significantly over time?
B) Does the extent of change in the thalamic volume correlate with the energy used to perform the treatment?

I want to regress out 'age' as regressors of no-interest

The way I have the model set up, is:

```
model <- lmer(ThalamicVolume ~ Age + Time + Energy  + (1 | Subject), data=data)
```

My data is set up  as follows (I actually have more subjects than this):

```
Subject <- c("sub1","sub1","sub2","sub2","sub3","sub3","sub4","sub4","sub5","sub5","sub6","sub6","sub7","sub7","sub8","sub8","sub9","sub9","sub10","sub10")

Time <- c("Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos","Pre","6mos")

ThalamicVolume <- c(92,80,95,82,88,72,75,68,87,50,90,60,92,89,80,77,81,80,88,85)
Energy <- c(80,80,72,72,81,81,79,79,85,85,74,74,33,33,44,44,39,39,28,28)
Age <- c(30,30,38,38,40,40,29,29,28,28,31,31,32,32,44,44,60,60,51,51)
data <- data.frame("Subject" = Subject,"Time"=Time,"ThalamicVolume"=ThalamicVolume,"Energy"=Energy,"Age"=Age).
```

Is this appropriate? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It didn't take long to  ind a very similar question and the answer is ... no, that's not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've looked through all of the related q's I can find, and can't seem to find a suitable answer.